# Resources for learning about the CLR

Tags: .net, clr

Can anyone suggest any books or websites which go into detail about how the CLR works? I've been trying to learn more about the detail of how my applications execute, but have found a relatively small number of resources.

There are a few great blog posts on MSDN, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) about object lifecyles. I've also recently bought Jeffrey Richter's excellent [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) which provides a great overview of how pretty much every C# construct translates into CLR.

I still want more detail though - it'd be great to cover every topic in CLR via C# in the same level of detail as the MSDN article. Any suggestions for blogs/books/articles which go into significant depth on the CLR?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that [Compiling for the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130622966) is quite good (but haven't read it myself).